# Positioning of footer text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a footer similar to the Airbnb one. I have been able to do the first two columns. However the third one is always slightly below the rest. I've tried:
Position: Absolute (however this makes it disappear) 
Position: relative (this works fine however it remove the links from the other two columns). 
Float: right and left but doesn't let me move it up.

I'm running out of ideas of what to do so if someone could help me that would be great. here is my code and a image of what I have made.

```css
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0.25px;
  background-color: #EF6248;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  /* NOTE: shadow of footer */
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* NOTE: where the footer sits on page */
}

.footer-links {
  color: white;
}

.footer-links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.col-1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.col-1 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-2 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
}

.col-2 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 550px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  positi
}

.col-3 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<footer>


  <div class="col-1">
    Revel
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> About us       </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Contact us     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ            </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Careers        </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    Event Host
    <hr>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why use Revel  </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Join Revel     </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    Event Service
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why partner with Revel  </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Guidebooks              </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ                     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Partner with Revel      </a></span>
  </div>


</footer>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0cK2.png)

Comment: Thank you all! Fixed the issues :) thanks again for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the things causing problems:

1. `positi` instead of `position:relative` in `col-3`
2. `float:left` to `col-2` as well

```css
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0.25px;
  background-color: #EF6248;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  /* NOTE: shadow of footer */
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  border: 10px solid green;
  /* NOTE: where the footer sits on page */
}

.footer-links {
  color: white;
}

.footer-links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.col-1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.col-1 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-2 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.col-2 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.col-3 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<footer>


  <div class="col-1">
    Revel
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> About us       </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Contact us     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ            </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Careers        </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    Event Host
    <hr>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why use Revel  </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Join Revel     </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    Event Service
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why partner with Revel  </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Guidebooks              </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ                     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Partner with Revel      </a></span>
  </div>


</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined col-1 and col-3 as float, you need to define col-2 also as float: left. See the code below I modified.

```css
footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0.25px;
  background-color: #EF6248;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black; /* NOTE: shadow of footer */
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 10%; /* NOTE: where the footer sits on page */
 }

 .footer-links {
   color: white;
 }
 .footer-links:hover {
   color: black;
 }

.col-1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
.col-1 span{
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-2 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
.col-2 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 550px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display:table;
  float: left;
  positi
}
.col-3 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<footer>


    <div class="col-1">
         Revel
             <hr>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> About us       </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Contact us     </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ            </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Careers        </a></span>
      </div>

    <div class="col-2">
         Event Host
         <hr>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why use Revel  </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Join Revel     </a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        Event Service
       <hr>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why partner with Revel  </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Guidebooks              </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ                     </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Partner with Revel      </a></span>
    </div>


  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are missing `float: left` on `.col-2` and `.col-3`. This will bring the third link group to the top. Then, you can set the `line-height` on `.col-3` to ensure that it aligns horizontally with the other two groups.

Also note that in the snippet below I have set a minimum width on the body to ensure that the columns don't wrap.

```css
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}

footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0.25px;
  background-color: #EF6248;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
  /* NOTE: shadow of footer */
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  /* NOTE: where the footer sits on page */
}

.footer-links {
  color: white;
}

.footer-links:hover {
  color: black;
}

.col-1 {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.col-1 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-2 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 130px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.col-2 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}

.col-3 {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.col-3 span {
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<footer>


  <div class="col-1">
    Revel
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> About us       </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Contact us     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ            </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Careers        </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-2">
    Event Host
    <hr>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why use Revel  </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
    <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Join Revel     </a></span>
  </div>

  <div class="col-3">
    Event Service
    <hr>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why partner with Revel  </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Guidebooks              </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ                     </a></span>
    <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Partner with Revel      </a></span>
  </div>


</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't make it too complicated. It is simple with few lines of style. check the example below.

```css
footer {
width: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 0.25px;
  background-color: #EF6248;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -6px black; /* NOTE: shadow of footer */
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 10%; /* NOTE: where the footer sits on page */
  
  color: white;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table;
 }

 .footer-links {
   color: white;
 }
 .footer-links:hover {
   color: black;
 }

.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3 {
 width: 30%;
 margin: 0 1.65%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<footer>


    <div class="col-1">
         Revel
             <hr>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> About us       </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Contact us     </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ            </a></span>
      <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Careers        </a></span>
      </div>

    <div class="col-2">
         Event Host
         <hr>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why use Revel  </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> test           </a></span>
      <span> <a href="#" class="footer-links"> Join Revel     </a></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
        Event Service
       <hr>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Why partner with Revel  </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Guidebooks              </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> FAQ                     </a></span>
       <span><a href="#" class="footer-links"> Partner with Revel      </a></span>
    </div>


  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [box-sizing: border-box;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to prevent width increasing because of padding.

```
footer *{
   box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Use [Flexbox](https://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html) for better alignment and positioning.

```
.footer{
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row /* works with row or column */
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-align-items: center;
   align-items: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4wL13wh6/1/)